# How can I change the output colors of `git branch -vv`

Tags: git, theme

I see that it takes a `--format` argument:

```
       --format <format>
           A string that interpolates %(fieldname) from a branch ref being shown and the object it points at. The format is the same as that of git-for-each-ref(1).
```

When I look at `man git-for-each-ref` I find

```
 When unspecified, <format> defaults to %(objectname) SPC %(objecttype) TAB %(refname).
```

and at the bottom it has these examples:

```
           --format='From: %(*authorname) %(*authoremail)
           Subject: %(*subject)
           Date: %(*authordate)
           Ref: %(*refname)

           %(*body)
           ' 'refs/tags'

--format="ref=%(refname)"
```

and then some more that I understand even less.

All I want is to change the shade of blue here. Help, please!
[image]

Comment: haven't tested it, but does  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320572/4433386) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;

- `git config -g color.branch.upstream 'red bold'`

---

Git Command:

```
git config color.branch.upstream '<fg-color> [<bg-color>] [<attribute>...]'
```

Git config file:

```
[color "branch"]
    upstream = <fg-color> [<bg-color>] [<attribute>...]
```

---

Possible `<fg-color>` and `<bg-color>` values:

```
black   blue   cyan  default  green
magenta normal red   white    yellow
```

Optionally prefixed with `bright` for brighter shades of those colours or use `#RRGGBB` values.

---

Possible `<attribute>` values:

```
blink   bold   ul   italic
reverse strike dim
```

---

Examples:

```
git config color.branch.upstream 'yellow red bold ul'
```

```
git config color.branch.upstream brightblue
```

```
git config color.branch.upstream '#c0c0ff'
```

See the `git-config(1)` man page for details and be aware that not every terminal supports everything. Also don't forget to use the --global flag to make the changes global :)

Comment: Link to the part of the man-page: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorbranch

Comment: Great Idea. Do it yourself and I will accept your edit, so you get the credits + 2 reputation :)